# jquery IE uploadify object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using tinymce and uploadify to create a email screen that allow the users to upload attachments.
It all worked well on chrome and on the IE 10 version I use.

However other versions of IE 10 and 11 it doesn't work as expected. Screen shrinks and it truncates the text.

Reading other similar errors suggested changing the jquery version 1.7.2
So I tried other versions but this caused the tinymce menu to vanish. 
This appeared to be caused by the property live and I replaced this with on.
The menu returned.

However now I get fileupload object doesn't support property or method.
one suggestion is to replace `</script>` with /> but this only makes the tinymce menu vanish again.

Any ideas on how to get this code to run on IE without errors?

```
`<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm19.aspx.vb" Inherits="CaseManagementTest.WebForm19" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title></title>
</head>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <style type="text/css">
        TD { FONT: 12pt verdana }
            .style9
            {
                width: 146px;
            }
    </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js" ></script> 
  <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnLookup").on("click", function () {
            $("#popup").dialog({
                title: "Email Address",
                Width: 600
            })
            return false;
        });

        tinymce.init({
            selector: ".tinymce",
            theme: "modern",
            menubar: false,
            resize: false,
            statusbar: false,
            plugins: ["advlist autolink lists charmap preview hr anchor",
            "pagebreak code nonbreaking table contextmenu directionality paste"],
            toolbar1: "styleselect | bold italic underline | pagebreak code preview | undo redo",
            toolbar2: "fontselect | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent"
        });

        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=FileUpload1x]").FileUpload ( {
                'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
                'cancelImg': 'Content/themes/base/images/cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Attach Files',
                'script': 'UploadVB.ashx',
                'folder': 'uploads',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true,
                'scriptData': { key: '<%=Key %>' },
                'onSelect': function (event, ID, file) {
                    $('#btnSendx0').prop('disabled', true)
                    $("#attachedfiles tr").each(function () {
                        if ($("td", this).eq(0).html() == file.name) {
                            alert(file.name + " already uploaded.");
                            $('#btnSendx0').prop('disabled', false);
                            $("[id*=FileUpload1x]").fileUploadCancel(ID);
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                },
                'onComplete': function (event, ID, file, response, data) {
                    $('#btnSendx0').prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td><a href = 'javascript:;'>[x]</a></td></tr>");
                }
            });
        });

        $("#attachedfiles a").on("click", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var fileName = $("td", row).eq(0).html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "VB.aspx/RemoveFile",
                data: '{fileName: "' + fileName + '", key: "<%=Key %>" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () { },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            row.remove();
        });

        $(function () {
            $("[id*=button1]").click(function () {
                ShowPopup();
                return false;
            });
        });
        function ShowPopup() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Email Addresses",
                width: 650,
                buttons: {
                    Exit: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        }
    </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function CloseWindow() {
             window.close();
             window.opener.location = window.opener.window.location;
         }
    </script>

   <body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
      <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text="Selected" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox id="selectedEmail" runat="server" Width="600px" ></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="600px" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" 
            PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="cn" HeaderText="Name"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="telephoneNumber" HeaderText="Tele"  />
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="mail" HeaderText="Email"  />
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style = "display:none"  />
        <center>
     <div style="FONT:700 20pt arial; COLOR:navy">Email</div>
        <hr/>

    <div>
        <table border = "0" style="width: 409px">


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Email*"></asp:Label><br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine"  Width="600px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="valRegEx" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contactX"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                    ValidationExpression=".*@.*\..*"
                    ErrorMessage="*Invalid Email address."
                    display="dynamic">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contactX" ErrorMessage="* Required" 
                    ControlToValidate = "txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr><td></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="lookup" runat="server" />

                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="lookUp"  ValidationGroup="look"  OnClick="btnlookup_Click"/>
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="look"
                    ControlToValidate="lookup"
                    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-z]{2,100}$"
                    ErrorMessage="* ."
                    display="dynamic">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
               </td>
             <td><asp:TextBox ID="email_or_cc" runat="server" Visible="false"  /></td>



            <tr>
           <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="CC*"></asp:Label><br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  Width="600px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contactX"
                    ControlToValidate="txtcc"
                    ValidationExpression=".*@.*\..*"
                    ErrorMessage="*Invalid Email address."
                    display="dynamic">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="ccemail" runat="server" />

                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="CC lookUp"  ValidationGroup="look"  OnClick="btnlookup_ClickX"/>
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="look"
                    ControlToValidate="lookup"
                    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-z]{2,100}$"
                    ErrorMessage="* ."
                    display="dynamic">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
               </td>
             <tr>
          <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Subject*"></asp:Label><br />
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="600px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contactX" ErrorMessage="* Required" 
                     ControlToValidate = "txtSubject"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign = "top" class="style9" >
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Body*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style9" colspan="4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" CssClass="tinymce" TextMode = "MultiLine"  Height="355px" Width="600px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contactX" ErrorMessage="* Required" 
                    ControlToValidate = "txtBody"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1x" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
               </td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table id = "attachedfiles">
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSendx0" runat="server" Text="Send" ValidationGroup="contactX" onClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true)" OnClick="btnSend_Click"  />
                         &nbsp; &nbsp;
                         <asp:Button ID="btnBack" Text="Back" runat="server" OnClientClick="CloseWindow()" ValidationGroup="contactX"   CausesValidation="false" />&nbsp;

               </td>
                  <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor = "Green"></asp:Label>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contactX"   ></asp:TextBox>
     </center>
 <center>
 </center>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: I have figured out that the fileupload has been replaced. if i replace it with      '$(function () {
                    $("[id*=FileUpload1]").uploadify({
                        'swf': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
                        'buttonText': 'Attach Files',
                        'uploader': 'uploadVB.ashx?key=<%=Key %>' It now works as before.

Comment: The problem now is  $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td><a href = 'javascript:;'>[x]</a></td></tr>"); doesn't  call the function anymore    $("#attachedfiles a").on ("click", function () ?